# Qgis 2.2 error plugin manager/installer error

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation

I get this error at startup

```
Ocurrió un error durante la ejecución del siguiente código:
import pyplugin_installer

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 217, in startPlugin
    msg = QCoreApplication.translate("Python", "%s due an error when calling its initGui() method" ) % errMsg
ValueError: unsupported format character ' ' (0x20) at index 2

Versión de Python:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Versión de QGIS:
2.2.0-Valmiera 'Valmiera', c3a2817

Ruta de Python:
['C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/Ing. Juan Bernnales/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/Ing. Juan Bernnales/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\bin', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Ing. Juan Bernnales\\.qgis2\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed problem: unninstall older versions, i had an 1.8 version

Answer (score 1):

Python might stumble over the blank in your Windows user account. This is used as folder name for your user folders, where the qgis python plugins are stored.

Try to create another Windows user without blanks and maybe also without `.`

Comment: but qgis 1.8 has the same user path and it runs perfectly with all plugin

Comment: There has been a lot of changes between QGIS 1.8 and 2.0 also affecting all python plugins. Maybe there is a function involved now that stumbles over the blank, which was not used in QGIS 1.8.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Can you try again with the 32 bit version of the QGIS Osgeo4w setup (NOT the standalone)?